# printf doesnt work properly while using threads

Tags: c, multithreading, posix

hi there a have a little problem with printf while using threads. problem is terminal prints one printf statement a little bit later which should be printed earlier. this is the part where i'm facing with this issue.

```
.
.
.
        while(1){

        printf("waiting for a connection\n");

        csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

        if((*csock = accept( hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= -1){
            printf("---------------------\nReceived connection from %s\n",inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
            client_counter++;
            pthread_create(&thread_id,0,&SocketHandler, (void*)csock );
        }

        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "Error accepting %d\n", errno);
        }
        }// end while
.
.
.
```

and this is the function which threads' use.

```
void* SocketHandler(void* lp){

    int *csock = (int*)lp;
    char buffer[1024];
    int buffer_len = 1024;
    int bytecount;
    char* str_exit="exit";

        while(1){

            memset(buffer, 0, buffer_len);

            if((bytecount = recv(*csock, buffer, buffer_len, 0))== -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error receiving data %d\n", errno);
            exit(0);
            }

            if(strcmp(buffer,str_exit)==0){
                break;
            }

            printf("Received bytes %d\nReceived string \"%s\"\n", bytecount, buffer);
            strcat(buffer, " SERVER ECHO");

            if((bytecount = send(*csock, buffer, strlen(buffer), 0))== -1){
            fprintf(stderr, "Error sending data %d\n", errno);
            exit(0);
            }

                //printf("Sent bytes %d Sent String %s\n", bytecount,buffer);
        }

    printf("Client disconnected\n");
    free(csock);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output is like this whenever a client (thread) connects to the server.

```
waiting for a connection
---------------------
Received connection from 127.0.0.1
waiting for a connection
Client disconnected
---------------------
Received connection from 127.0.0.1
waiting for a connection
Client disconnected
```

when the first client connects the output works properly, but when the second one connects the string `"waiting for a connection"` comes after `"Received connection"`. well it should work in contrast way. i will be glad if you can help and thanks anyway

Comment: You probably need to think about `fflush()`.  You may need to think about [`flockfile()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/flockfile.html) and `funlockfile()`.

Comment: Where is the problem - I don't see it: waiting/received, waiting/received, waiting.  That is how you coded it and is the output I would expect.  The accept thread starts, waits, then receives two connections and then waits for another.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler well actually put `fflush(stdout)` either above and below of `printf("waiting for a connection\n");` but still output was the same

Comment: That's because there is nothing wrong with the output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no issue.  Apart from the first time the loop is entered, 'waiting for a connection' will be the last thing printed by the accept thread after a client connects.

Put another way, this loop starts/ends at the accept() call except when entered for the first time.  It is the first time through that is the 'exception', not the subsequent loops.

Comment: yeah finally i realized the order is true. my fault :)

Answer (score 1):

```
setbuf(stdout,NULL);
setbuf(stderr,NULL);
```

**Turn off output buffering**. printf is **not re-entrant**, so it synchronizes using global-locks.
When output is being buffered, one thread might not release its lock before another starts printing.

It is always advisable to **[turn off output buffering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4220911/why-to-turn-off-the-standard-output-buffer-when-multithreading)** or call [`fflush()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/fflush) manually, when multithreading

Comment: i tried calling `fflush(stdout)` exactly on above and below of `printf` statement. but none of them worked

Comment: ..because there is nothing to fix!

Answer (score 1):

There's not a problem (or at least what you're describing isn't a problem). Here's some annotated output:

```
waiting for a connection             # 1
---------------------                # 1
Received connection from 127.0.0.1   # 1
waiting for a connection             #   2
Client disconnected                  #        thread handling connection 1
---------------------                #   2
Received connection from 127.0.0.1   #   2
waiting for a connection             #     3
Client disconnected                  #        thread handling connection 2
```

If you change your while loop slightly, the output will become self documenting:

```
int i = 0;
while(1) {

    printf("%d: waiting for a connection\n", i);

    csock = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int));

    if((*csock = accept( hsock, (struct sockaddr*)&sadr, &addr_size))!= -1) {
        printf("%d: ---------------------\n%d: Received connection from %s\n", 
            i, i, inet_ntoa(sadr.sin_addr));
        client_counter++;
        pthread_create(&thread_id,0,&SocketHandler, (void*)csock );
    }

    else{
        fprintf(stderr, "%d: Error accepting %d\n", i, errno);
    }

    ++i;
}// end while
```

You might want to add a similar ID for your thread to print out - for example, instead of passing in a single `int` representing the socket, pass in a small struct that contains the socket and the `client_counter` (or `i or something more useful) value at the time the thread was created.

Comment: At last - someone else gets it!  I thought it was me that was going insane:)

Comment: sorry guys i havent noticed and got crazy. thanks for the revealing reply :)

Comment: @quartaela - no need to aplologise.  Loops that stop in the middle because of blocking calls are just one of those multithreading things that you will get used to after a bit:)

Answer (score 0):

If you're mixing use of stderr and stdout, you cannot expect proper ordering unless you flush after each use. Things get even more complicated with multiple threads (flushing is not going to be sufficient), so I think you should pick one stream (either stdout or stderr) and stick with it.

Comment: is there a way to use both of them properly _? or using only one of them is the only way from void any complication

Comment: If you want to mix use of both when they might refer to the same underlying file or terminal, you'll get corrupted output (possibly interleaved at random). The only way to avoid this would be to create your own mutex protecting both stdout and stderr, and lock it whenever you want to write to either one.